# Filter only to show durtion

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10/3/2022 18:21:40 | correct |
| 10/3/2022 18:22:50 | incorrect |
| 10/3/2022 18:28:00 | correct |
| 10/3/2022 18:34:00 | incorrect |

From the above table, I want only filter out and show on the table if the time difference between "correct" and "incorrect" is > 5 minutes

Comment: why would a value be correct vs incorrect? is it because the 5 minute duration between the time values?

Comment: the actual value is different on the original task I just put correct and incorrect  just to assume there is a value and the value happens at that time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes there is always only two alternating rows of correct and incorrect, and returns a column showing the duration in minutes between them. You can then filter that, since you were vague on how and what to filter

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Time", type datetime}, {"Value", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "MinuteDuration", each if [Value] = "incorrect" then null else Duration.TotalMinutes(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Time]-[Time]),type number),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"MinuteDuration"})
in  #"Filled Down"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve your problem.

1. Make sure your date data is sorted chronologically ascending. (this can be done in Power Query.
2. Create an Index Column in Power Query

[image]

3. Close Power Query and add the following calculated column to your table

```css
IfNextRowOverFiveMins = 
var currentRow = 'Table (2)'[index] --this should be the index on your rable
var nextTime =LOOKUPVALUE('Table (2)'[time],'Table (2)'[index],currentRow+1) --this function looks up the time for the next entry
var timeDiff = DATEDIFF('Table (2)'[time],nextTime,MINUTE) --the datediff function finds the difference in days/hours/minutes between two date values
return IF(timeDiff>=5,TRUE(),FALSE())
```